# Recording speakers at community meetings

Tags: audio-recording

I’m live-streaming several community meetings onto Facebook. I'm usually sitting right on trying of the main speaker but when there is a presentation off to the side or question from the audience then the level drops off.   What can I do? I can't mic the presenters or questioners. These rooms vary but they are generally what you'd think as a large meeting room, from 80 x 25 to an amphitheatre.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you mic the presenters or the questioners? Because that's what any professional sound recordist would do. Try having a static mic that questioners approach when asking a question - also put a static mic on a lectern when they are delivering a presentation. If you can't put mics up for the presenters or questioners, then there's little else you can do that's useful.

Comment: Absolutely ^ - the only way if you don't have good room mics is to mic up your presenters and questioners